# What is the difference between revolutions and iterations in phpbench?

Tags: php, performance

I already read [the documentation](https://phpbench.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annotributes.html), but when testing, I'm still not able to understand well the difference between them.

For example, with this simple file:

```
<?php
    class StackOverflowBench
    {
        public function benchNothing()
        {
        }
    }
```

When I set 1000 revolutions, and only one iteration, here is my result:

| subject | set | revs | its | mem_peak | best | mean | mode | worst | stdev | rstdev | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| benchNothing | 0 | 10000 | 1 | 2,032,328b | 10.052μs | 10.052μs | 10.052μs | 10.052μs | 0.000μs | 0.00% | 1.00x |

the `best`, `mean`, `mode` and `worst` are always the same, which means they are based on the only iteration I made.

When I run it with 10 revolutions and still 1 iteration, I have this:

| subject | set | revs | its | mem_peak | best | mean | mode | worst | stdev | rstdev | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| benchNothing | 0 | 10 | 1 | 2,032,328b | 10.200μs | 10.200μs | 10.200μs | 10.200μs | 0.000μs | 0.00% | 1.00x |

which seems to mean the times calculated are not a sum of all the revolutions, but something like an average for each iteration.

If I wanted to measure the best and worst execution time of each time the method is executed, I'd try 1000 iterations and only 1 revolution each, but it takes waay to much time. I launched it with 100 iterations of 1 revolution, here's the result :

| subject | set | revs | its | mem_peak | best | mean | mode | worst | stdev | rstdev | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| benchNothing | 0 | 1 | 100 | 2,032,328b | 20.000μs | 25.920μs | 25.196μs | 79.000μs | 5.567μs | 21.48% | 1.00x |

This time, the time seems to be at least twice as long, and I'm wondering what I didn't understand well. I may be using these informations badly (I know my last example is a wrong one).

Is it necessary to measure the best and worst of each revolution, like I want to do ?
What are the interests of iterations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Revolution vs iteration

Let's take your example class:

```php
class StackOverflowBench
{
    public function benchNothing()
    {
    }
}
```

If you have 100 revolutions and 3 iterations, this is the pseudo code that will be run:

```php
// Iterations
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    // Reset memory stats code here...
    // Start timer for iteration...

    // Create instance
    $obj = new StackOverflowBench();

    // Revolutions
    for($j = 0; $j < 100; $j++){
        $obj->benchNothing();
    }

    // Stop timer...
    // Call `memory_get_usage` to get memory stats
}
```

## What does the report mean?

Almost all of the calculated stats (`mem_peak`, `best`, `mean`, `mode`, `worst`, `stdev` and `rstdev`) in the output are based on individual iterations and are [documented here](https://phpbench.readthedocs.io/en/latest/report-generators.html#generator-table-columns).

The `diff` stat is the weird one and [document here](https://phpbench.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reports.html?highlight=diff#difference-between-rows) and [mentioned elsewhere](https://phpbench.readthedocs.io/en/latest/report-generators.html?highlight=diff#table) as:

> the percentage difference from the lowest measurement

When you run a test, you can specify what column to report the difference on. So if you `diff_column` on run time, if iteration #1 takes 10 seconds and #2 takes 20 seconds, the `diff` for #1 would be `1.00` (since it is the lowest) and #2 would be `2.00` since it took twice as long. (Actually, I'm not 100% sure that is the exact usage of that column

## Measuring revolution vs iteration

Some code needs to be run thousands or millions of times in a task/request/action/etc. which is why revolutions exist. If I run a simple but critical block of code just once, a report might tell me it takes `0.000` seconds which isn't helpful. That's why some blocks of code need to have their revolution count kicked up to get a rough idea, based on possible real-world usage, how they perform under load. Array sorting algorithms are great examples of a tightly-coupled call that will happen a lot in a single request.

Other code might only do a single thing, such as making an API or database request, and for those blocks of code we need to know how much system resources will they take up as a whole. So if I make a database call and consume 2MB of, and I'm expecting to have 1,000 concurrent users, those calls could take up 2GB of memory. (I'm simplifying but you should get the gist.)

If you look at my pseudo code above, you'll see that setting up each iteration is more expensive than each revolution. The revolution basically just invokes a method, but the iteration calculates memory and does instantiation-related work.

So, to your second-to-last question:

> Is it necessary to measure the best and worst of each revolution, like I want to do?

Probably not, although there are [tools](https://www.blackfire.io/) out there that will tell you. You *could* for instance, find out how much memory was used before a method and after to determine if your code is sub-optimal, but you can also do that with PHPBench by making a 1 iteration, 1 revolution run and looking for methods with high memory.

I'd further say that if you have code that has great variance *per revolution*, it is almost 100% related to IO factors and not code, or it is related to the test dataset, and most probably size.

You should hopefully know all of your IO-related paths, so benchmarking the various problems related to those paths really isn't a factor of this tool.

For dataset-related problems, however, that is interesting and is a case where you'd want to know each run potentially. There, too, however, the measurements are there to know either how to fix/change your code, or to know that your code runs with a certain [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is perfect!